# Datetimepicker does not display properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php as a DatetimePicker widget on my site.

However, the positioning is completely off. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have been Googling for the longest time and tried several fixes, but nothing seems to work.

The widget (which is on the bottom of the page somehow) should be next to the Incident Date/Time textbox.

[image: Faulty Positioning]

Comment: give z-index:99999999 in your date picker css//

Comment: Didn't work, sorry..

Comment: Add some code to your question, otherwise no one is able to help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xwfd0Lrj/

Comment: But the bloody Datepicker does not even initiate here. Could it be the order of the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problems, I check the demo provided by the official, it has the same problem on my browser, so I change the version
of `datetimepicker`, and it fixed. this is the content of `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`

https://jsfiddle.net/zhangyu911013/rpyo9zLb/2/

Comment: delete the space in the url,it seems i cannot post without code...hope it'll help you..